# Reading a messy excel file with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-analysis

I have been looking for solutions to this problem on stack exchange and beyond, and so far I'm not able to find a one.

I'm sure someone has encountered this problem before: I'm writing a python script which will extract and repurpose some data from an excel file - the catch being that the excel file is rife with irregular formatting and extraneous data. So, before I can get down to the table of data I need:

[image: Table I need]

I have to go through tables like this:

[image: Table I don't need]

My plan is to use some kind of regex or string recognition to know where to split the file so I can get to what I need. But the problem I'm having right now is that pandas freaks out whenever I try to run read_excel on this file.

```
In [4]: df = pd.read_excel(open('data.xlsx','rb'), sheetname=0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-21f5fee2b08d> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_excel(open('data.xlsx','rb'), sheetname=0)

/Users/Gus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.pyc in read_excel(io, sheetname, header, skiprows, skip_footer, index_col, names, parse_cols, parse_dates, date_parser, na_values, thousands, convert_float, has_index_names, converters, engine, squeeze, **kwds)
    168     """
    169     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 170         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    171 
    172     return io._parse_excel(

/Users/Gus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.pyc in __init__(self, io, **kwds)
    223             # N.B. xlrd.Book has a read attribute too
    224             data = io.read()
--> 225             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
    226         elif isinstance(io, compat.string_types):
    227             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)

/Users/Gus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.pyc in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    420                 formatting_info=formatting_info,
    421                 on_demand=on_demand,
--> 422                 ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
    423                 )
    424             return bk

/Users/Gus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.pyc in open_workbook_2007_xml(zf, component_names, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    831         x12sheet = X12Sheet(sheet, logfile, verbosity)
    832         heading = "Sheet %r (sheetx=%d) from %r" % (sheet.name, sheetx, fname)
--> 833         x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)
    834         del zflo
    835 

/Users/Gus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.pyc in own_process_stream(self, stream, heading)
    551                 self.do_dimension(elem)
    552             elif elem.tag == U_SSML12 + "mergeCell":
--> 553                 self.do_merge_cell(elem)
    554         self.finish_off()
    555 

/Users/Gus/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlrd/xlsx.pyc in do_merge_cell(self, elem)
    607         ref = elem.get('ref')
    608         if ref:
--> 609             first_cell_ref, last_cell_ref = ref.split(':')
    610             first_rowx, first_colx = cell_name_to_rowx_colx(first_cell_ref)
    611             last_rowx, last_colx = cell_name_to_rowx_colx(last_cell_ref)

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

The whole point of my writing this program is so that I **don't** have to go in to every single one of these files and delete information by hand. But how can I automate this process if python won't even accept the file? I'm hoping someone here will have encountered a similar problem before. What was your solution?

Comment: have you tried skipping rows with something like `skiprows=9`

Comment: You could consider doing preprocessing outside of pandas with something like `openpyxl` to extract the relevant information from the spreadsheets.

Comment: the "table you don't need" looks like it just has summary information (a.k.a. no data)

Comment: @3novak how would you go about lopping of the useless data with openpyxl? I'm not very familiar with it, but I understand it's an important tool for python/excel wor